# Python port scanner producing garbled output

Tags: python-3.x, port, python-multithreading

I'm trying to make a threaded port scanner but it does not work the way i expected it to.The code when producing an output, generates a garbled output.I know it is because some threads have finished before others so they print their output to the screen but i do not know how to prevent it.

```
import threading
import socket

portlist = [21,22,25,80,110,443]
open = []
closed = []
failed = 0
length = 0
ip = None
site_ = None
ip = None
def portscan(site,port):
    global failed
    global length
    global failed
    global length
    global ip
    global site_
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((site,port))
        open.append(port)
        s.close()
        print("[SCANNING...]")
    except:
        closed.append(port)
        failed = failed + 1
        print("[SCANNING...]")
    length = length + 1 

def statistics():
    try:
        avg = failed/length*100
    except:
        avg = 0
    print("<PORTS OPEN>")
    print(open)
    print("<PORTS CLOSED>")
    print(closed)
    print("PACKETS SENT:",length,"| PACKETS LOST:",failed,"[",avg,"% loss]")

def main():
    site_ = input("/ENTER SITE IP OR NAME/>")
    try:
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(site_)
    except:
        ip = "COULD NOT GET IP"
    for port in portlist:
        t = threading.Thread(target = portscan, args = (site_,port))
        t.start()
    print("<---SCAN STATISTICS FOR",site_,"[",ip,"] RETURNED--->")
    statistics()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

wait = input("")
```

Here is the output i got when i ran the code on a specific website.As you can see the ports that are open and closed print before the program finishes scanning

```
<---SCAN STATISTICS FOR www.gmail.com [ 74.125.68.18 ] RETURNED--->
<PORTS OPEN>
[]
<PORTS CLOSED>
[]
PACKETS SENT: 0 | PACKETS LOST: 0 [ 0 % loss]
[SCANNING...]
[SCANNING...]
[SCANNING...]
[SCANNING...]
[SCANNING...]
[SCANNING...]
```

What I want is the threads to be finished before the ports are printed out.

Comment: To better help you can you provide invalid output also? I doubt many SO users take time to execute your script.

Comment: Also worth noting that the global variables used by different threads should be synchronized to avoid invalid data - http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

Answer (score 1):

You should wait (call **.join**) for your threads to finish

```
threads = []
for port in portlist:
    t = threading.Thread(target = portscan, args = (site_,port))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
#now wait for them to finish
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```